# CASE and MERGE when loading data from CSV in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am loading data from a CSV file which looks like this:

```
id,snakValue,property
Q1666473,Q15,owned_by
Q7393205,Q16,subsidiary
Q5949310,Q16,parent_organisation
Q14906468,Q17,owned_by
```

This is the cypher-shell code I am using:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///properties.csv" AS row
MATCH (a:Entity {eid:row.id})
MATCH (b:Entity {eid:row.snakValue})
CASE row.property
    WHEN "owned_by" THEN MERGE (a)-[:owned_by]-(b)
    WHEN "subsidiary" THEN MERGE (a)-[:subsidiary]-(b)
    WHEN "parent_organization" THEN MERGE (a)-[:parent_organization]-(b)
    ELSE MERGE (a)-[:board_member]-(b)
END
```

However, I am getting this error

```
Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' (line 6, column 3 (offset: 156))
"CASE row.property"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I can easily split my properties file according to the property value and re-write my `LOAD CSV` query without `CASE`. But I was hoping if there's an optimal way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a `MERGE`, `MATCH` or `CREATE` inside a `CASE`, you can only use it inside a `RETURN` (or `WITH`).

In your case you should create 4 scripts with a `WHERE` on your property  at the begining like that :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///properties.csv" AS row
WITH row WHERE row.property = owned_by
  MATCH (a:Entity {eid:row.id})
  MATCH (b:Entity {eid:row.snakValue})
  MERGE (a)-[:owned_by]-(b)
```

Or in APOC there is a function to create a dynamic relationship :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///properties.csv" AS row
  MATCH (a:Entity {eid:row.id})
  MATCH (b:Entity {eid:row.snakValue})
  WITH a, b
  CALL apoc.create.relationship(
    a, 
    coalesce(row.property, 'board_member'),
    {​}, 
    b
  ) YIELD relationship
```

Comment: This is exactly what I figured and executed a couple of minutes ago! Thanks for your reply. Have accepted the answer and upvoted.